# Best fitting geodesic on a sphere

Tags: geometry, 3d, spherical-coordinates, geodesic, spherical-geometry

Given a list of points (latitudes and longitudes) on a sphere, I want to find the geodesic which minimizes the sum of squared deviations from the geodesic to the points.

Is there a nice and efficient way to do this?

Comment: See https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00207160.2014.884277?mobileUi=0&journalCode=gcom20

Comment: See also https://core.ac.uk/reader/55627030   . This one  too https://towardsdatascience.com/geodesic-regression-d0334de2d9d8